# SSDT not generating statements for permission

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I have a SSDT project which setup to not drop anything.

Now I am trying to:

1. Add script to create new role
2. Add script to grant permission to the role created at step 1
3. Assign role to login without using SSDT

Now, the script to create new role (1) working fine, but there are nothing for the permission (2), I have tried to grant SELECT on schema/table but both not showing up in the resulting script.

I guess I am missing something but have no idea what it is, any pointer are welcome.

Comment: Try to go through all the publish profile settings, you might missed something

Comment: Thanks, tried to go through again but nothing interesting found, at the end it seems to caused by access right of the user used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the issue is nothing to do with the options but the user I use.

I am using a user with role `db_ddladmin`, `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` which will not generate the statement but also no error or warning.

Tried to use another user with role `db_owner` then the statements is showing up as expected.

So the problem is about permission but not SSDT options.